# Circumvent the build process without AppleTeam ID, TeamID and so on

Tags: applications, xcode, apple-id

TL;DR;
How to compile non-apple products without involving Apple Inc.

How do you circumvent this stuff in/for/with XCode for project like Wireguard and compile like normal programmers?

I downloaded the git/zip from their official repository
https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-apple/about/

At the very beginning they say to modify this file.

```
// Developer.xcconfig

// You Apple developer account's Team ID
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = <team_id>

// The bundle identifier of the apps.
// Should be an app id created at developer.apple.com
// with Network Extensions capabilty.
APP_ID_IOS = <app_id>
APP_ID_MACOS = <app_id>
```

> Should be an app id created at developer.apple.com

No. Just No.

I just want to make all. No name, No ID, No cert (neither for free nor for money). Just, no. I have borrowed a mac, the user has supposedly an ID.

To summarize:
I want to **Compile** from **source code** to an **executable object**. Like you would do for any normal, sane OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile from source code without involving Apple. This is possible with Xcode and with traditional command line tools.

Try running [`xcodebuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) within the Xcode project directory. It probably will not work the first time, but the process will be closer to your non-macOS expertise.

### Code Signing on macOS

Code signing is required on macOS. As you have encountered, this typically involves Apple and having a Developer ID.

You can ad-hoc code sign your executables. This [limits their acceptance](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288291) to the local computer but this is likely what you want.

To ad-hoc code sign the executable `a.out` use the `-s -` flag:

```
codesign -s - a.out
```

You may also be able to use the `-` identity within the `.xcconfig` configuration files.

Alternatively, you can [disable the various security features](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection) of macOS.

Comment: Thanks @Graham. It will take me days to orient myself. I am now following the lead for Ad-hoc sign with - within the .xcconfig. 
So far I seem to understand it's also about "ad-hoc provisioning profile"...ngl I don't think I will be able to build this anytime soon.
The problem is the project requires this in possibly multiple points. I see many CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY variables grep -r the whole Project ... I am not sure what I am doing. But I am going to put a dash after the "=" in .pbxproj because to put a dash in Developer.xcconfig seems to not be the way.

Comment: Sorry to hear it does not trivially work. You should be able to build the executables with Xcode or `xcodebuild` and disable the code signing stages. Then you can focus on the ad-hoc signing as a post-build task. Good luck!

Can you download a pre-signed binary anywhere?